# How to remove or uninstall tensorflow1.1 or 1.8 on macOS

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, pip, uninstallation

I try to use the tensorflow to run code, but the version of tensorflow is 1.1 and something is wrong with my code just because the low version. So I decide to update tensorflow. 
I use conda command:

```
pip install --upgrade --ignore-installed tensorflow
```

Then I get the tensorflow1.8.0, but I find a question about this.
 "We do not yet provide a Tensorflow 1.8.0 package on macOS."--https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9294

So I refer to tensorflow official website and I use this command to install tensorflow1.6.0:

```
pip install -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple --ignore-installed --upgrade \
 https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

Finally, I get the 3 different versions of tensorflow on my conda list just like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V11BM.png)

But my code is running correctly and I print the version of tensorflow, I get the output:

```
import tensorflow as tf  
print(tf.__version__)
1.6.0
```

So,I want to remove or uninstall tensorflow1.1 or 1.8 versions, how should I  do next ?

Comment: Do you want TF 1.8 or 1.6? Why not go with the newest version? Have you tried `pip uninstall`?

Comment: Also: Don't get conda and pip confused, they are two different things. You are using pip here, not conda. Therefor you are not limited by what is available in the conda channels